# Making fixed-width rectangle that floats in center of screen

Tags: css

The CSS code below creates a rectangle of variable width, always 250 pixels from the left edge of browser and 30 pixels from right edge of browser.

How can I create a rectangle of fixed width 1,000 pixels, centered in browser (and flush to left side of screen if browser is made narrower than 1,000 pixels)?

Thanks in advance,

J. W.

```
.loginbackground {
position: absolute;
height: 73px;
left: 250px;
right: 30px;
top: 20px;
text-align: left;
margin-bottom: 3px;
padding: 0px;
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
background: powderBlue;
}
```

Comment: what kind of browser support do you need? Can it have a wrapper div?

Comment: @natedavisolds just Amazon Kindle Fire Silk browser (the one that came out yesterday).  Just kidding... I would like full cross-browser functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `margin` property to `0 auto` will center a div:

```
div {
    width  : 500px;
    height : 100px;
    margin : 0 auto;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/dEdqk/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flexbox to achieve it. You could find a good introduction here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.conatiner{
  background-color: #efefef;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="conatiner">
  <span>Centered</span>
</div>
```